# Validate the length of an input be exactly 10 in a form with html5

Tags: jquery, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form (bootstrap V.3.0) and I want to check that the length of the input will be exactly 10. I want to use an HTML5 solution so I used the `pattern=".{10,10}"` but it doesn't work...  Here is the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/127873)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id9" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input type="number" name="j_phone" id="id9" pattern=".{10,10}" class="form-control" placeholder="phone number" required>
        </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">ok</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `type="number"` and the `pattern` attribute together. So instead change the type to text and modify the pattern to only allow numbers.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}">
```